# Are there records of soldiers opinions of canned food in WWI?

Tags: world-war-one, food

While reading the Wikipedia article on [canning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canning), I came across the following statement (with no citation).

> Throughout the war, British soldiers generally subsisted on low-quality canned foodstuffs, such as the British "Bully Beef" (cheap corned beef), pork and beans, canned sausages, and Maconochies Irish Stew, but by 1916, widespread dissatisfaction and increasing complaints about the poor quality canned food amongst soldiers resulted in militaries seeking better-quality food to improve morale, and complete meals-in-a-can began to appear.

They were eating canned food, and it seems it was exceptionally bad. Are there records of soldiers exact opinions of this food? Also, the leaders of the time probably also would have discussed the food the soldiers were eating and their own opinions of this. Are there records of this? Or can someone point me to a good source regarding food quality for soldiers in WW1?

Comment: If you Google 'canned food ww1 soldiers complaints', you'll see there's a Spartacus education article [Trench Food](https://spartacus-educational.com/FWWtrenchfood.htm) with primary sources quoted (mostly British soldiers).

Comment: in the book [All Quiet on the Western Front](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_Quiet_on_the_Western_Front) an autobiography of a german soldier in WWI there is an episode in which german troop during an attack on british trench they catch all the food (and canned food specially) they can ("We bagged five tins altogether. The fellows over there are well looked after; they fare magnificently, as against us, poor starving wretches, with our turnip jam; they can get all the meat they want." ) - so I guess that from german point of view in the late stage of the war was considered a gluttony